# How to find all values of a parameter such that given matrix has determinant zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $\lambda$ be real. Find all values of $\lambda$ for which the
>   determinant of the matrix $A\lambda I_3$ is zero, where
>
> $$A= \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 1  \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1
>  \end{matrix} \right ]. $$

I have calculated that $\det(A) = 2$ and $\det(I_3) = 1$ so $\det( 2\lambda 1 ) = 0$.

How to find all values of $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already calculated, $\det(A) = 2$. We also know that $\det(\lambda I_3) = \lambda^3$, so by the multiplicativity of the determinant one has

$$\det(A \lambda I_3) = \det(A) \det( \lambda I_3) = 2 \lambda^3.$$

This expression is zero if and only if $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: @Cat6969 I edited my answer.